# Checking if context is total

Tags: powerbi, dax

What might be an alternative way, possibly more effective, for checking if context is total. I use this measure as benchmark:

```
IsTotal1 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Tab[Store]), ALLSELECTED(Tab)) = COUNT(Tab[Store])
```

The idea is that it calculates COUNT on a table with filters removed (left side, so we get counts for all dimensions in context) and checks it against the COUNT with current context. If both are the same, we have total.

I know that using the function `HASONEVALUE` might be tempting:

```
IsTotal2 = NOT(HASONEVALUE(Tab[Store]))
```

However, using this approach has a serious drawback. If we make a table displaying sales by store and by product then the first measure will work and the second will fail. Moreover, if we display sales by product only the first measure will still work, and the second should be retyped to `HASONEVALUE(Tab[Product])`.

So I want the measure to be resistant to any change of granularity due to adding new dimension to table visual.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @Aldert I reworded my first sentence.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `ISFILTERED('Tab')` instead of `HASONEVALUE`?

Comment: @Dan I get an error when trying to use whole table as a parameter of `ISFILTERED` with a message "Parameter is not a correct type". I can put there a column but this leads me nowhere.

Comment: Calling ISFILTERED with a table argument is [actually valid syntax](https://dax.guide/isfiltered/) even though Power BI displays an error message... just try to pull the measure into a visual to check that it actually works. This is not an unsupported feature btw. It's just a bug in the DAX editor of Power BI...

Comment: @Dan yes, amazingly it is processes despite the error message. But it returns FALSE for every line, also for total. So I cannot make any use of it.

Comment: Are you slicing by a column directly on the `Tab`-table, or on a related table? If you're slicing by a column on a related table, you should use `ISCROSSFILTERED('Tab')`.

Comment: @Dan ISCROSSFILTERED('Tab') returns True everywhere, also in Total.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you have a page- or report level filter. In that case, you have to either stick with your approach (perhaps changing COUNT(...) to COUNTROWS(Tab) could improve the performance slightly), or write something like `ISINSCOPE('Tab'[Store]) || ISINSCOPE('Tab'[Product]) || etc...` where you repeat `ISINSCOPE` for every column that could potentially be used to slice the data.

Comment: @Dan put that as answer please so I can accept it. I do not like to leave questions open, if there is no reason to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided in the comments, it sounds like you have a page- or report level filter. In that case, you can't rely on functions such as [ISFILTERED(...)](https://dax.guide/isfiltered) or [ISCROSSFILTERED(...)](https://dax.guide/iscrossfiltered), as these external filters or slicers could impact the result returned from these two functions.

So you have to either stick with your approach (perhaps changing COUNT(...) to COUNTROWS(Tab) could improve the performance slightly), or write something like

```
ISINSCOPE('Tab'[Store]) || ISINSCOPE('Tab'[Product]) || etc...
```

where you repeat [ISINSCOPE](https://dax.guide/isinscope) for every column that could potentially be used to slice the data, as ISINSCOPE is the only function that distinguishes using a column on a filter/slicer vs. using it as a row/column grouping on a table/matrix visual.